# Wpf performance question: Opacity on Brushes vs Opacity on Elements

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml

I want to know why setting the `Brush.Opacity` value of element rather than setting the element's `Opacity` property is better for performance.

*From MSDN: [Modifying an element's `Opacity` property can cause WPF to create a temporary surface.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613584.aspx#Opacity)*

But I can't understand what is **temporary surface**
Can any one explain?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a temporary surface is created, it means a new bitmap is created for the element, the element's contents are rendered to it, and *then* it is composited onto the parent element's surface using the opacity provided.

Otherwise, if you just set the opacity of the brush, it can bypass this step and just draw directly to the parent element's surface.

Creating a new bitmap and compositing it is more expensive than just drawing directly.